# How the Reference itself is passed

Tags: c++, reference, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Being a **value semantic** language, `C++` passes all parameters *by value*. So when I pass pointer to an object, the object is *passed by reference*, but the `pointer` itself is *passed by value* (although I believe the object is **not  passed** at all, only the `pointer` is, and we access the object inside the function *by reference*. I think this idea  also conform to **value semantics**, since if I thinks like this, **value semantics** becomes more meaningful, *Nothing is passed except value*).

So thinking this way makes sense for `pointer`, as a `pointer` to something is itself an object, which has both `lvalue` and `rvalue`. While passing a `pointer` as a parameter, a copy of the `rvalue` is sent, like any other object (ex. passing an integer).

But what about `reference`? Theoretically, `reference` is not any individual object, id does not have any identity, simply an alias to the object it refers to. Common implementation of `reference` may be on top on `pointer`, but what about uncommon implementation? Even if implemented in terms of `pointer`, is it passed by value?

Comment: A reference is treated like a pointer, I think. The compiled binary will not be different than if you had used a pointer.

Comment: There's a lot of confusion here, I believe.

Comment: Most likely an address will be pushed on the stack or put in a register, so yes you can think of pointer and references as if they were themselves being passed by value :)

Comment: I've just closed as duplicate. This question is answered in so many other questions already: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308368/pointers-vs-references-vs-a-regular-pass-by-value-c), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563553/when-do-you-want-to-use-pointers-vs-values-in-c), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/c-when-to-use-references-vs-pointers), [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776010/pass-by-reference-and-value-with-pointers) ..

Comment: @sashoalm, Drax he is talking about *semantics*, where passing references means call-by-reference. That the underlying implementation of the compiler *might* treat references like pointers is not of interest in semantics. The compiler might even inline the code and therefore inserting the called function into the calling environment instead of passing any arguments into the function - you *could* call that "pass inside out", but semantically its still calling a function.

Comment: .. [6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240161/reason-to-pass-a-pointer-by-reference-in-c), [7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174144/default-value-for-a-reference-to-a-pointer), [8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732706/c-passing-arguments-by-reference-and-pointer).

Comment: @Drax in my opinion that's an implementation detail noone should care about. If I declare a local variable x and a reference to x in the next line, why should the compiler waste space to push the address of x on the stack? For all I care a reference is an alias, how it's implemented doesn't concern me at all.

Comment: @Jefffrey, I guess you should have atleast read carefully before marking as duplicate.

Comment: @RakibulHasan, could you please tell what did I miss?

Comment: @Jefffrey, as Arene pointed out, I am not interested in difference between pass by value/pointer/reference, I wanted to know about pass by reference in terms of value semantics, about what standard says , about the underlying implementation of compiler.

Comment: If you're interested in the underlying implementation, then it makes no sense to talk about whether C++ references are passed by value, because when you get to the underlying implementation, you're no longer dealing with C++.

Comment: @RakibulHasan the problem I see is that the standard doesn't define how things are implemented, it doesn't tell if signed numbers should be implemented as two's complement or one's complement. Hell, it doesn't even require a stack/heap. It just tells how things behave, not how they are implemented.

Comment: @RakibulHasan, what do you mean by "value semantic"? The linked questions deal with both underlying implementation (which is of no concern to the C++ standard) and standard.

Comment: @ArneMertz & Raphael Miedl, i agree with both of you but i think the OP already gets the fact that it is implementation defined :)

Comment: "C++ passes all parameters by value" - are you sure you're not confusing C++ with Java?

Comment: @Cubbi, when we send any pointer to an object, the object is sent by reference, but the *pointer* itself is sent by value, that's what I meant. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: @RakibulHasan: That point is correct. He's not referring to pointers, he's referring to reference parameters. When you pass an object into a function which has a reference parameter, the passed object is passed by reference. It's the same point that was made by David in the very first comment.